# Format specifier in C not clear

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    float b = 6.412355;
    printf("%.*f\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Why the output is;

```
6.412
```

What is the effect of .* here ?

Comment: [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is the first result of google **printf c**.

Comment: instead of cplusplusref, prefer the community-driven **[cppreference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)**. it's more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` means that the next characters indicate the precision to use. The `*` means to read the value from the argument list; in your case, it will read `a`. The value is 3, so the next argument is printed to 3 decimal places.

Comment: if you had a=4, the answer is 6.4124, but I was expecting 6.4123

Comment: Is that what the documentation *said* you should expect?

Comment: @user2799508: printf rounds to nearest. Since the next digit is `5` it means up, so `6.4124` is correct output for 4 decimal digits precision.

Answer (score 2):

In `printf` function, the format `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier` of this question is `.precision`, it has two choices number or `*`.

When `*`, it means The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

For more details, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: what should i say....

Comment: follow your heart. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf 1. I'm not the downvoter, I actually give it an upvote when the context is added. 2. I agree that telling OP to read to document is the best way. That's what I did in the comment of the question. 3. However, link-only answers are not good answers, it would be flagged and deleted by moderator if it doesn't provide any context.

Comment: @YuHao: Thanks, but... The link WAS self-descriptive, so it's good on its own (also, it's IMO far better than the link you provided in comment, although that served mainly to show "no effort" from OP). Any more than the self-descriptive link would just be noise. No doubt some/most SO moderators would not understand that, but we should strive to do the best for the community, not being conflict-shy re people who have campaigned themselves into a mod job on the site.

Comment: All that was good about this answer: conciseness, up-front self descriptive good link, no ready-broiled fish, is now gone. Argh.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main() {
int a = 3;
float b = 6.412355;
printf("%.*f\n",a,b);
return 0;
}
```

It substiutes the value of `a` to the `*`,implying a precision.